# Rails as_json performance issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-activerecord

I have an array of Active model records. The array will have at max about 75 objects in it.  However the model is complicated with multiple associations and relationships. Right now I am overriding the as_json method to include only the necessary fields.  This is taking about 13 seconds to load 60 objects.  How can I speed this up? I have tried removing some of the more complicated queries such as get_vehichles with the assumption I could load that later but it does not seem to help performance significantly.

```
 def as_json
 hash = {}
 hash["title"] = calendar_title
 #hash["description"] = calendar_description
 hash["start"] = start_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 hash["end"] = end_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 hash["url"] = "/admin/appointments/#{id}"
 hash["base_amount"] = base_amount
 hash["start_at"] = start_at
 hash["end_at"] = end_at
 hash["tech_id"] = technician_id
 hash["asset_id"] = asset_id
 hash["customer_name"] = customer.full_name(false)
# hash["customer_id"] = customer_id
 hash["id"] = id
# hash["cust_addresses"] = customer.addresses
 hash["address"] = address
#   client_host = ClientHost::Location.find_by_id(address.client_host_locations_id)
# hash["customer_email"] = customer.email
# hash["customer_wholesale"] = customer.wholesale?
# hash["customer_tax_exempt"] = customer.tax_exempt?
# hash["vehicles"] = self.get_vehicles
end

def get_vehicles

vehicles = []
self.appointment_vehicles.each do |av|
  hash = {}
  hash["appointment_vehicle"] = av
  hash["total_amount"] = av.total_amount
  hash["vehicle"] = av.vehicle
  hash["package_display_title"] = av.package.display_title
  hash["package_amount"] = av.package.amount
  hash["upgrades"] = self.get_upgrades(av.upgrades)
  vehicles.push(hash)
end
return vehicles
```

end

Comment: Can you show the query to retrieve the records from the database ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm getting you here but I'll give it a dig

```
require 'oj'
def get_vehicles
  vehicles = self.appointment_vehicles.map do |av|
    {
      appointment_vehicle: av,
      total_amount: av.total_amount,
      vehicle: av.vehicle,
      package_display_title: av.package.display_title,
      package_amount: av.package.amount,
      upgrades: self.get_upgrades(av.upgrades)
    }
  end

  vehicles
  # Oj.dump(vehicles) <-- if you need this hash as json
end
```

How's that?

Other than that, the activerecord query will be what's taking the most time.  It'd be good if you can share the SQL query it executes when you retrieve your records?